# how can i make number of restful service calls an single time in JavaScript Easy way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make 20 services calls at a time in Pure JavaScript or Ajax calls.
Is there any better way to do?

Can you please help me?

Comment: It is better you use node.js

Comment: Hi @TintuCRaju, I make one service call, Success call back i make second service call, But i want make all the service calls at single time. Can we make it possible

Comment: "better you use node.js" based on what, the question explains nothing. OP can you post your code so that people can offer suggestions.

Comment: I want to Avoid 20 http Requests @TintuCRaju

Comment: That is not what the question states. Converting 20 calls into one single call would be quite an undertaking. If you can limit the number of calls, good, but one shouldn't be afraid to make multiple calls.

Comment: Yes @TintuCRaju, i Want avoid 20 http Requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `$.when()` function to make multiple `$.ajax()` requests at the same time.

It would look something like this

`$.when($.ajax(options1), $.ajax(options2))
  .then(successFunc, failFunc);`

This works since the `$.ajax()` is a Promise-compatible object it, but it would look quite nasty with 20 requests.

You can instead pass an array of `$.Deferred()` objects to the `$.when()` function with the that you want to do.

It would work as below

```
//Function to wrap the requests inside an array
function getRequests(){
    var arrayOfDeferred = [];

    //Wrap the below in a loop or something to get your 20 requests
    //Push the ajax call to the array
    arrayOfDeferred.push(
        $.ajax({url: "...", success: function(result){
            //maybe do something when the request is done?
        }});
    );

    return arrayOfDeferred;
}

//Use it like this
var requests = getRequests();
$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function() {
    console.log("All requests are made!");
});
```

Of course you would have to adapt the code to get the requests correctly, depending on how they differ from each other, but this should give you the basic idea of how it can be done.

Check out the documentation for  [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [`$.deferred()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) .

Comment: Hay @Daniel it was super and very nice, Is there any way to do with out using JQuery. I mean Pure JavaScript

Comment: Yes, but it would be alot more coding to do so. You can make the requests using `XmlHTTPRequest`s but handling the promises-features would require alot more.